# How to get Firestore Native storage usage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, storage

I am working on a migration of my Firestore Native database and I need to estimate the time and costs this is going to take.

I am mainly concerned about the total storage usage of the database. I know Google provides an explanation of [the Storage size calculations](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/storage-size), but am I supposed to do the calculations myself every time I need to know how much data I have on my database?

Looking at the [Cloud monitoring metrics](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage#cloud-monitoring) I cannot find a way to get this information. I would expect Firestore Native to have something similar to Firestore in Datastore mode, in which we can see the total size in the Cloud Console Dashboard:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtcGZ.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is hard to find. It seems there is a workaround for it.

It's possible to use `gcloud` command to export whole Firestore database to storage ([reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import)). Than you can use `gsutil ls` command to list all objects ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls)).

I tried on my testing database with those commands:

```
$ gsutil mb -l <same-location-as-firestore> gs://<your-firestore-bucket>
$ gcloud firestore export gs://<your-firestore-bucket>
$ gsutil ls -rl gs://<your-firestore-bucket>
```

If you have Firestore in your default location, you do not have to use `-l` in first command.

This will list all objects with size and with summary like that at the end:

```
TOTAL: 3 objects, 32932 bytes (32.16 KiB)
```

I have to warn you that this will cost (I think around 0.026$/GB). But if you do not have really huge database total shouldn't be high and acceptable.

I hope this will help!

Comment: Hi @vitooh, thanks for providing this answer. It seems like this is going to be more complicated than I expected. Unfortunately, I estimate more than a million records in the database, and considering the cost to perform this export to GCS you are suggesting, I don't think it would be viable to do this just to know how much data I have in the DB.